# Pure geometry proof of parabolic mirror property

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics, geometry

Is there a proof of the property that parallel rays of light incident upon a parabolic mirror converge to its focus that does not resort to Cartesian coordinates?

[image]

Comment: There is. But it requires a shift in your thinking away from what physicists are comfortable with. We think of a parabola as the curve defined by functions like y=x^2. You want to think in terms of geometry, where a parabola is the intersection of a plane and a cone where the axis of the cone is parallel to the plane. This question might do better on the math site.

Comment: You might also read "The Archimedes Codex" It goes through some of the math used by Archimedes. One of the problems involves a parabola, where we would use Cartesian coordinates, and of course he did not. It's a good read.

Comment: Have a look here and remember that the parallel rays travel equal distances to reach the focus and so arrive in phase with one another. http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa08/Wisdom/EMAT6690/Parabolanjw/reflectiveproperty.htm

Comment: Conic Sections ? Math SE.

Comment: Here is an attempt with the formula for the equation of the line reflected by another line + using the equation of the tangent of the parabola  `x^2` with its derivative: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852497/formula-for-the-equation-of-the-reflection-of-a-line-on-another-line-and-applic

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's plenty such proofs, but the choice between them depends on which of the [multiple equivalent definitions of a parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) you take, and exactly what restrictions you place on the allowed proofs.

Physicists normally think of parabolas as the locus of equations of the form $y=x^2$, but you're explicitly looking for something with no formulas, so you probably need to change that as well. The next likeliest candidate is defining the parabola as [the locus of points equidistant from a point and a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Definition_of_a_parabola_as_locus_of_points), which ties you in to all the proofs of classical geometry. Under that understanding, the proof of the reflection property is a staple of euclidean compass-and-straightedge geometry, and [Wikipedia has a suitable proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Proof_of_the_reflective_property), based on a construction of the form

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parabel_2.svg)</sup>

In short, with $C$ on the directrix, you define $B$ as the midpoint of $\overline{FC}$, which means (since $\overline{FE}=\overline{EC}$ by definition of the parabola) that $\angle FEB=\angle BEC$, so you just need to show that the line joining $B$ and $E$ is tangent to the parabola. The Wikipedia proof relies on some facts from calculus, though if you want a calculus-free proof you can probably find one by rooting around in the toolbox for the euclidean geometry of conic sections.